# samba path not found

Tags: unix, share, samba

I am trying to set a samba server on my Linux redhat server.

My server is at machinename.myschool.edu, I can ping and ssh to it without problem.

My smb.conf looks like this:

```
[sharename]
comment = my share
path = /home/username
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
valid users = username
```

I restart the samba service after editing smb.conf.

However, I am not able to connect to it both on my mac and pc, using the samba server address:

```
\\machinename.myschool.edy\sharename
```

Mac give me error :"server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time"
PC: "The network path was not found"

I am also not able to see my machine with the "smbtree".

Could anyone suggest how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to connect to it from your PC? Also, does the Mac's Finder see `machinename.myschool.edy` under Network?

Comment: hi mbrath, thank you for replying. Yes I am able to connect to it from both my pc and mac. by ping or ssh

Answer (score 1):

From a Unix-based system, to access a Samba share on another system from the command line, you need to use `smbclient` or use `mount` to mount a share drive.

You can list shares available from a system running Samba using this command:

```
smbclient -L //machinename.myschool.edy
```

If you want to access a file share, you can mount it as follows:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=user_name //machinename.myschool.edy/sharename /place/to/mount
```

It should prompt you for the password for `user_name`. And this assumes `user_name` has permission to access the share as given by the Samba configuration of the server you are accessing.

There are various online resources that describe more details such as: http://www.linuxnix.com/2009/09/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux.html or http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client